# PyDev: not seeing module within project

Tags: pydev

PyDev 2.5 and Django 1.4

I'm very new to this, and am probably making some stupid mistake, but I've looked around and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

After creating a new app  within my project and then adding it to INSTALLED_APPS in the project settings file, I attempt to run the server (RunAs --> PyDev: Django) and get:

Error: No module named < appname >

Originally I thought this was being caused by the error reported here (error creating settings.py): http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3512322&group_id=85796&atid=577329

But updating to the nightly build solved that. (Note: The project's Django module settings field remains blank initially, but it seems to find it when I type it in manually).

Yet it still can't find the app/module. Maybe I am just missing something obvious here, but I'm really not seeing it.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue in the way you're writing your code and the PYTHONPATH that's configured...

For a better answer, please give more details on those (a screenshot from the pydev package explorer with your project structure and the INSTALLED_APPS setting should suffice).